# Weird borders in VmWare Player Unity mode

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I have a question concerning unity mode in Vmware Player. When I run apps in unity mode, they get an annoying gray border (first picture).

This, in it self is just annoying. The problematic thing is that when I run it in maximized mode, the top border is still there, but the mouse pointer doesn't react to it, making all my clicks being about a mm over where I'm actually pointing (second picture)

Anyone have any idea why this border appears? And can it be removed?

[image: The problem in maximized]
[image: The problem in windowed]

EDIT: It's not the VmWare borders setting, this is my exposure when the borders are present (Picture 3), and when I turn on borders, my weird borders have borders (Picture 4)

[image: Borders are windows of their own]
[image: Borderception!]

Answer (score 4):

It's a setting in VM Player.

[image]

Source: [VMware Workstation 10 Documentation Center](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-DBC4C0EB-4161-4419-A856-EA2CE1B90DAA.html)

Comment: This setting is already off, and is not responsible for the weird borders I'm experiencing. I've tried turning this setting on and off without result

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and could identify thoses borders. 
This are the shadows of windows from Win7.

I disabled Aero Mode and it helped for windows like Explorer. But I still have the same effect on Office 2013, which integrate window shadows.

Here some explanations from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2821007

According to Microsoft:

> Microsoft Office 2013 applications use a custom frame in which a thin
>   border is surrounded by four transparent Window handles (hWnds) that
>   are used to render shadows. These hWnds are designed to make resizing
>   the application easier. There is no user setting to disable these
>   shadows. However, you can disable them (and re-enable them) by calling
>   SendMessage or SendMessageTimeout together with the parameters in the
>   code snippet that appears in the "Sample Code" section.
>
> The following function sends a message to an Office application’s hWnd
>   to enable or disable the shadows around the application frame. (Some
>   error checking is omitted for brevity.)

```
#define WM_MSO                              (WM_USER + 0x0900) 
#define WM_MSO_WPARAM_OMFRAMEENABLESHADOW   117
#define WM_MSO_LPARAM_SHADOW_ENABLED        1
#define WM_MSO_LPARAM_SHADOW_DISABLED       0

void DisableShadows(HWND hwndOfficeApp)
{
    SendMessage (
        hwndOfficeApp,
        WM_MSO,
        WM_MSO_WPARAM_OMFRAMEENABLESHADOW,
        WM_MSO_LPARAM_SHADOW_DISABLED);
}

void EnableShadows(HWND hwndOfficeApp)
{
    SendMessage (
        hwndOfficeApp,
        WM_MSO,
        WM_MSO_WPARAM_OMFRAMEENABLESHADOW,
        WM_MSO_LPARAM_SHADOW_ENABLED);
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not easy to use, while you need to write code. 
I found a solution published on http://www.thomaskoetzing.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=379&Itemid=254 based on Microsoft KB, which run this code given by Microsoft as an Service.

Just download and install this OFF2013_ShadowOff.zip. It will install a service that run on the Win7 guest VM.
Once this service is started, thoses borders will be removed in Unity mode!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is linked with a program, which need to be downloaded from this website.